# How to force Excel add-in to load default settings on FIRST start up

Tags: excel, vba, settings, excel-addins

I am developing a small Excel add-in for a company's internal use. I have an issue with settings for some of the procedures.

Some of the variables inside my macros have modifiable settings, for example, a macro which changes number format to user-defined one, or shortcuts for some of the macros. I have dedicated user-forms for those settings and I save/read them to/from Windows registry using those forms. Users can also set default settings - this is a simple system with SaveSetting/GetSetting procedures.

However, I have an issue with loading the settings on start up. I need the add-in to load DEFAULT settings the FIRST time it is launched, and then USER settings next time the add-in is launched. I know how to load default settings, but I cannot figure a way to load default settings only once, and then load user modified settings (changed, or default, depending on their choice through the mentioned user-forms). Right now I am only aware of a way how to load default settings EVERY TIME the add-in is loaded...

Did anyone have this kind of issue and is willing to help?

Comment: When your add-in loads, check for a flag in the registry which you set when the user saves their preferences: based on the absence or presence of the flag then load either the default or the saved preferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the add-in is first time loaded, it will create a key in Registry, having the value, let us say, `True`. When add-in is loaded, in the `Workbook_Open()` event, that specific key is checked. If it does not exist (or it is `False` if you sometime will need to reset the add-in), the default settings will be loaded...

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 Dim regValue As String, MyApp As String, myKey As String, keyValue As String
  MyApp = "MyAddin": myKey = "add_default": keyValue = "Default"
  regValue = GetSetting(MyApp, myKey, keyValue, "No value")
  If regValue <> "No value" Then
        If CBool(regValue) = True Then GoTo Continue
        'load default settings
        SaveSetting MyApp, myKey, keyValue, "True"
  Else
        'load default settings
        SaveSetting MyApp, myKey, keyValue, "True"
  End If
Continue:
  'your code without loading default
  '.....
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment and the code. I will definately try it! Can you tell me, what CheckBox1 represents? What is it for?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment on your post yet due to my current privilege.

But looking at your issue:

1. The first time, you can store a Default setting in the Addin itself you will call during the event `ThisAddIn_Startup` which is loading the Adding.
2. Then you store the setting in 2 ways based on the need:
   2.1. If it is a General Setting shared with other persons then you better use **INI files** to store the setting when the Admin for example set the initial settings.
   2.2. If it is each User Setting then you better store them in the Registry:
   2.2.a. Where you create the keys on the first set up
   2.2.b. Store the user settings using the recently created keys.
3. Then next time the Application loads, you use the `ThisAddIn_Startup` to check if the keys were already created:
   3.1. If it is YES, then you just read the stored settings.
   3.2. If NO then you start on Step #2 again.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thank you for your idea. I will try to create this kind of system, I just need to think it through :)

Comment: You're welcome @RafałKowalski. I'm exactly working on an Excel Addins struggling like you few days ago, so I understand you very well. I didn't post any code yet as the structure is more important than the code. Then once you took your decision coding will just follow.